# Описание меток - разрешены ли изображения?

Tags: поддержка, метки, описание-метки

Дважды создавал описание метки [wxwidgets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wxwidgets). Оба раза оно куда-то пропадает "в никуда" - даже я сам его после этого не вижу. Подозреваю, что это связано с тем, что я пользовался возможностью вставки изображения и добавлял в описание логотип wxWidgets.

Это так и должно быть или это дефект? Если изображения не разрешены, может, надо убрать эту возможность вовсе? Ну или хотя бы просто удалять их, но не терять сами описания - сил нет третий раз начинать...

Comment: У вас в профиле отображается список сделанных вами предложений. Если вы туда загляните, то увидите причину, почему предложение не было принято. Также можете кинуть сюда ссылку на проверку в очереди, тогда обсуждение проблемы будет более предметным.

Comment: В [tag:telnet] было то же самое. Стоило хотя бы оформить цитату. )

Answer (score 9):

У вас был копипаст из Википедии. Это - нарушение лицензии Википедии (копируя что-то из нее, надо указывать источник). Кстати, на этом сайте аналогичные требования.

Кроме того, это несколько противоречит духу SO - тут генерируют новый контент, а не копируют старый.

Вам следует переписать описание wxWidgets своими словами.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно.